# Kiosk Application Android

Tags: android, launcher, kiosk-mode

I will do a kiosk application.I have examined many examples from Stackover and GitHub.And I tried.But these applications work as launchers.That is, when you select home button press launcher.Application needs to work directly.Without the choice of a launcher.How can I do it.I'm new to android.Rejoice if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove intent filter category from `Activity` inside `Manifest' file